# Xamarin.Android Error: unauthorized access to “/system/lib/libsqlite.so”

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I have researched this for hours and can't figure out how to fix this issue. Every time I launch my app i get the error stated in the title.  I currently have sql-net by Frank Krueger nuget package installed. I reference 'using SQLite;' in my code which looks at SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs.  I was reading that installing the nuget package sql-net-pcl by Frank Krueger can resolve this issue? If so, how would I use this since I can't reference the two SQLite classes anymore if I do install it.

Comment: Does this issue happens on Android version 7.0 or higher and works fine on other version?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I was reading that 7.0 only allows internal libraries be used which is why when referencing sqlite I am getting the error. But I have no clue how to get around this.  If i don't reference sqlite then how would I use sqliteconnection and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I currently have sql-net by Frank Krueger nuget package installed.

You're using the old `SQlite` version which is not compatible with Android 7.0 and higher version, if you installed the some SQLite relative library, please refer to this doc: [Preparing for Native Library Linking Changes in Android N](https://blog.xamarin.com/preparing-for-native-library-linking-changes-in-android-n/), and try to update your library as the doc suggested.

For sql-net package, you can try to install the sqlite-net-pcl package.

Comment: Okay so if i install sqlite-net-pcl should i uninstall sql-net package then?

Comment: @Freiza1991, yes, and please install the newest package.

Comment: Okay so i uninstalled sqlite-net and installed sqlite-net-pcl.  I rebuilt and deployed but I am still getting the splash error.  Is it because i am still using sqlite.cs?

Comment: @Freiza1991, I'm sorry, I don't quite understand, what do you mean by using sqlite.cs?

Comment: Sorry I am confused as well. So i am 'using sqlite;' which is how i can sqliteconnection etc. When i remove 'using sqlite;' then i get multiple errors where i try to use sqliteconnection. I have a sqlite.cs class which is where sqliteconnection class is.

Comment: @Freiza1991, you mean that you cannot use the Api of old version sqlite package? Shouldn't be, the apis of two packages are the same, did you use the new package's namespace in your code?

Comment: these are my sqlite references:
Mono.Data.Sqlite
Sqlite-net
SQLitePRCLRaw.batteries_green
SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2
SqlitePCLRaw.core
SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3
SQLITEPCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3

Comment: I am unsure what the API namespace of the new package is.  I know the old package is sqlite.

Comment: @Freiza1991, check this doc: [Using SQLite.NET](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/).

Comment: So it stated to 'using sqlite;' which is what I am dong.

Comment: Ugh all i had to do was remove sqlite.cs because it was being referenced twice. One in that class and one in the dll that i installed with sqlite-net-pcl

Comment: @Freiza1991, you've your own sqlite.cs as a class in your code? .....Yeah, remove this and just use the one in Package.

Comment: Btw thanks for the help!  The answer was uninstalling sqlite-net and removing sqlite.cs from my project. Then installing sqlite-net-pcl rebuilding and deploying. No more splash error!